# match second character regex mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I was watching this mysql course where it the following example was given:

```
SELECT Name, Continent, Population FROM Country WHERE Name LIKE '_%a' ORDER BY Name;
```

And they said that `'_a%'` would match all strings in the `Name` column whose second character is `a`. I'm using MariaDB server 10.0.34 on Ubuntu and in my case, the result is quite different. Instead, it shows all strings in the `Name` column who end in `a`. Any idea why that is and where the difference exists?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm. A couple of points.

1) those are not regular expressions, those are LIKE comparisons. (Yeah, yeah,  to-may-toh, tah-mah-toh, I know.) But we can be *precise* in our terminology, and avoid confusion and obfuscation.

2)  `'_%a'` and `'_a%'` are *significantly* different, as your own observations have revealed

- `_` underscore matches any one character
- `%` percent matches zero, one or more of any character
- `a` matches the character `'a'`

So

- `LIKE '_a%'`  matches any single character, followed by an 'a', followed by any number of (zero, one or more) characters
- `LIKE '_%a'`  matches any single character, followed by any number of (zero, one or more) any characters, and ending with an 'a'

---

As a demonstration:

```
  SELECT 'name'  LIKE '_a%'    -- true   - at least two chars, second char is a 
       , 'name'  LIKE '_%a'    -- false  - at least two chars, last char is a 

       , 'name'  LIKE '_e%'    -- false  - at least two chars, second char is e
       , 'name'  LIKE '_%e'    -- true   - at least two chars, last char is e
```

Those are `LIKE` comparisons. To do the equivalent using *regular expression*, something like this:

```
  SELECT 'name'  REGEXP '^.a'     -- at least two chars, second char is a 
       , 'name'  REGEXP '^..*a$'  -- at least two chars, last char is a 

       , 'name'  RLIKE  '^.e'     -- at least two chars, second char is e
       , 'name'  RLIKE  '^..*e$'  -- at least two chars, last char is e
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. Indeed, I realised afterwards that I got those two confused.

It's good to know that they're named differently, I don't take terminology lightly if it is meaningful. And in this context they're clearly two different things